# creating random and unique vectors in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to create cells that are random on a grid, that are unique (i.e. no cells overlap with each other) and that are connected (so no cell is floating freely). I use vector2 for the position of each cell and there is always one cell at position 0,0

Here is the function I came up with:

```
def create_cells(number_of_cells):
    cell_grid = []
    cell_grid.append(pygame.math.Vector2(0,0))

    while len(cell_grid) < number_of_cells: 
        new_cell = random.choice(cell_grid).xy 
        new_cell[random.choice((0,1))] += random.choice((-1,1)) 
        for existing_cell in cell_grid: 
            if new_cell != existing_cell:
                cell_grid.append(new_cell)

    return cell_grid
```

I basically pick an existing cell, move it by one unit and then only append the new cell to the cell grid if that cell is unique.

But the for loop doesn't seem to remove duplicates and I am ending with lots of overlapping cells and I can't seem to understand why that is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 2: I added an explanation of the OP's bug at the end under 'Edit 2'.

This does not address the bug you are asking about, but I am going to suggest a better approach to your problem.

I would suggest that you keep a list of cell edges that do not have cells adjacent to them and then just pick a random entry from that list. Remove that edge once you have added the new cell and add any new edges from the newly added cell that do not already have a cell adjacent.

That seems better and much faster then trying various ones until you get one that does not collide, since the only options will be ones that will succeed.

Actually it probably makes sense to track the open adjacent cells rather than the free edges, but it is more or less the same thing,

Am I missing something about the problem that precludes this?

Edit:
One significant difference between these two approaches is that your solution randomly chooses between cells whereas my suggestion chooses between open edges. Yours will apply equal weight in the choice to a cell that has one open edge as one that has three open edges, where my suggestion will be three times more likely to choose the cell with three open edges (since it is choosing among the free edges). That difference may matter depending on how you want the tiles placed.

Edit 2:
I took a look at your code and this part is problematic:

```py
        for existing_cell in cell_grid: 
            if new_cell != existing_cell:
                cell_grid.append(new_cell)
```

First, you should NOT iterate over a list and change that list at the same time. That can mess up the iteration. It is especially bad if you are deleting items from the list, but it is also bad if you add to it. In this case you when I ran your code it added the `new_cell` to the end of the `cell_grid` list and then the `for` loop when it got to the end checked `cell_grid` against itself.

Second, you are not checking if `new_cell` is in the list before you add it.

You check if it is not the same as each entry in the list and add it each time it is not. So say on the 3rd pass you have `(0, 0)` and `(1, 0)` in the list and it chooses `new_cell` of `(0, -1)`. It will compare it to `(0, 0)` see it is not that and add `(0, -1)` to the list and then it will compare it to `(1, 0)` see it is not that and add `(0, -1)` to the list again. As the list gets bigger it will add the even more copies of `new_cell` to the list.

As much of a problem is that it will add the entry even if it is in the list already, since it will add it for each entry that is not a match and will only not add it for the comparisons that are a match. Lets continue the previous example where it now has `new_cell` = `[(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, -1)]` and it now picks a `new_cell` of `(0, 0)`. It will match against the first entry and so not add it, but will then continues through the rest of the entries not matching and will add it 4 times for each of those other entries.

Is there a reason that you are not just doing:

```py
        if new_cell not in cell_grid: 
            cell_grid.append(new_cell)
```

That would work, though it still spends a lot of time trying cells that are already in the list and not adding them. It gets worse as the list gets larger and the likelihood of a match increases.

Keeping a list of the valid options and choosing from them as suggested above would work better from that perspective.

Comment: interesting approach! My rationale was that I would only ever need a small number of cells, maybe 50 at the most, and this seemed like a decent approach...

Comment: thank you so much. I honestly feel silly now for not just using your approach, it is so much more elegant!